# URL Rewriting with php htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I have a URL that looks like:

> url.com/pages/login.php 
> url.com/pages/NewClient/index.php
>                          
> url.com/pages/NewClient/page1.php
>                          
> url.com/pages/NewClient/page2.php etc.

How would I go about converting that URL to:

> url.com/login/ 
> url.com/panel/
>                
> url.com/page1/
>                
> url.com/page2

How do I go about making friendly URLs in PHP?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [URL rewriting with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388959/url-rewriting-with-php)

Answer (score 0):

For handling it in PHP, you can add the below line in the `.htaccess` file

`FallbackResource route.php`

This way all the URLs will get landed to `route.php` first.

This file will have all the logic for routing and mapping.

You can have the logic to look for the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and render content accordingly using basic condition statements.

For more information on FallbackResource directive, refer [doc](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_dir.html#fallbackresource)

Or for something as plain as your requirement, you can simply handle this directly in the `.htaccess` file by adding the below rules.

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^login$  pages/login.php   [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^panel$  pages/NewClient/index.php  [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^page1$  pages/NewClient/page1.php  [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^page2$  pages/NewClient/page2.php  [NC,L]
```